# Redirect gfortran -v

Tags: bash, gcc, gfortran

I was trying to script storing some info about which compiler was being used with:

```
gfortran -v 2>&1 >some.file
```

But upon inspection some.file is empty (plus gfortran printed its output to the terminal). The easy solution is just to store instead:

```
which gfortran
```

but i'm curious as to why -v doesn't pipe output on stdout/stderr, presumably it is outputting on some different file handle that eventually ends up on my terminal?

Comment: In particular, note the answers which talk about the order of redirection.  That is, `gfortran -v 2>&1 >some.file` is different from `gfortran -v > some.file 2>&1`.

Comment: dam, never realized the order matters, gfortran -v > some.file 2>&1 works for me

Comment: Tangentially, recent versions of gfortran offer the `compiler_version` function from the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.